# Getting ClassCastException when trying to create an array of an inner class type

Tags: java, classcastexception

I'm trying to make a linked-list  representation of Deque , each node of the linked list is defined by an instance of the inner class `Node` , but I'm getting this :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LRandomizedQueue$Node;
```

I dony know how to work this out. This is what i had:

```
private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Node[] nd = (Node[]) new Object[100];
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong , and help me figure this out ? 
Thanks a lot for your time.

**Edit:** It seems i had things confused with creating a generic array vs an array of an inner class. Thanks a lot for the replies.

Comment: You're creating an `Object[]` and trying to cast it to a `Node[]`. Would you expect `Node node = (Node) new Object()` to work?

Comment: Always quite a good idea not to have @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an array of Objects and then trying to cast them to an array of Nodes; you need to create an array of Nodes

try

```
private Node[] nd = new Node[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private Node[] nd = (Node[]) new Object[100];
```

It Should throws `ClassCastException`. It is not possible to cast array object to `Node` object.

Create like -

```
Node[] nd = new Node[100];
```

Comment: It's worth noting it's possible the other way around, while it (arguably) shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

```
private Node[] nd = (Node[]) new Object[100];
```

Why would you do this?

You are clearly casting wrong objects to wrong reference types.

The object is of type `Object[]` and you are casting it to `Node[]`, which will never work.

Do this instead.

```
Node[] nd = new Node[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need : `private Node[] nd = new Node[100];`

Because Arrays are themselves objects, since `new Object[100]` will return an object of array class you can't cast it into some other class object which here is `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an object array and try to cast it to `Node` array. this kind of casting is not allowed because object is not a `Node`

you can do

```
Node[] nd = new Node[100];
```

if you need an array of `Node` or

```
Object[] nd = new Object[100];
```

if you need just an array of objects

for future, you should know that usually when you get `ClassCastException` that means you have tried to cast a class to other class when the case is invalid, and should try to understand the hierarchy of the objects